# How to Deactivate Trigger using Apex code

Tags: trigger, api, metadata

I want to deactivate a trigger on an object or all the triggers on an object using apex code using metadata api or partner api, but i'm not finding a way to do it exactly. Could anyone plz help with that.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this from Force.com IDE.

Find the `trigger.meta.xml` of respective trigger and make this change and deploy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexTrigger xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>40.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Inactive</status>
</ApexTrigger>
```

Answer (score 4):

If the triggers are in your own code base, you can add your own switch (or switches):

```
public class Triggers {
    public static Boolean areDisabled = false;
}

trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {
    if (Triggers.areDisabled) return;
    ....
}
```

Or the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_triggers.htm) for ApexTrigger includes the status value that can be set to Active/Inactive/Deleted. You can call that from [Apex](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L1907).