# How can I change the status of Apex Trigger using Apex Programming(Tooling/MetaData API)

Tags: apex

How to Activate or Deactivate Trigger from Apex code using Tooling API or Metadata API??
Please Help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?Can you add it as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189594/how-to-deactivate-trigger-using-apex-code

Comment: @ManishAnand  Bcoz I have task to make a lightning component which shows all available triggers  in org  and we can activate/deactivate from the component with the help of  toggle button which is associate with each trigger records.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_triggers.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

> I have task to make a lightning component which shows all available triggers in org and we can activate/deactivate from the component with the help of toggle button which is associate with each trigger records

This is not a good trigger control mechanism. You'll have to also cope with unit test management and coverage - your trigger tests will likely fail if you turn your triggers off, making it difficult for you to perform deployments in your production Salesforce org.

Instead of attempting to perform Metadata API deployments to activate and deactivate triggers, build into your triggers or trigger handler framework a mechanism for suppressing their operation using Custom Metadata or Hierarchy Custom Settings.

Your trigger can inspect the value of the Custom Metadata or Custom Setting before taking action, and do nothing if it's been configured to be disabled. You can implement this at the granularity of a whole trigger or a specific trigger event, and if you choose to use Hierarchy Custom Settings, you can scope configuration to a user, profile, or entire organization.

This can be as simple to implement as

```
trigger MyTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    if (MyCustomSetting__c.getInstance().Triggers_Disabled__c) return;
}
```

or it can be as sophisticated as building out an enablement facade class that you call from each trigger event in a handler class to determine whether to execute for that specific combination of trigger, sObject, event, and running user or profile.

You can then managed these trigger settings records directly in Salesforce Setup, rather than writing code to control them, or if you do prefer a custom UI, your Lightning components can interact with setup records rather than performing deployments. In the latter case, Hierarchy Custom Settings are an easier implementation because they don't require a Metadata API deployment to update.

Comment: Suppose We have 5 triggers then will have to create 5 custom records as well??

Comment: It depends on your implementation and how granular you want the control to be. But potentially, yes.